# How to get the body of the response using async HTTP GET with Fuel

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, get, fuel

I have the following HTTP GET call using Fuel:

```
uri.httpGet().responseObject<Array<Data>> { _, response, result ->
        result.fold(success = {
            getSuccessMessage()
        }, failure = {
            val msg = "Error: ${it.message}"
            val errorData = response.data.toString() //always throws Exception               
        })
```

When I get an unauthorized call (returning *status code 401*), I need to have the response body.

As I use the *async way*, I [learned](https://ryanharrison.co.uk/2018/06/15/make-http-requests-kotlin.html#language-kotlin%20highlighter-rouge) that **the requests are done on a dedicated threadpool**.

Unfortunately, I always get a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` when I try to read the response.

How could I get the message properly?

Answer (score 3):

For network on main thread exception ,this is the solution based on coroutine.It handles the error on network call as well.

In your `ApiService.kt` file have a wrapper function like below.

```
class ApiService {
    suspend fun getAsyncWay(url: String): Any? {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

            val (request, response, result) = Fuel.get(url)
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .responseString()

            when (result) {
                is Result.Failure -> {
                    println("Inside the Fuel Failure result  ${String(response.data)}")
                    return@withContext String(response.data)
                }
                is Result.Success -> {
                    val data = result.get()
                    println("Inside the Fuel Data Success result $data") // you can also use ${String(response.data)
                    return@withContext data // response.statusCode is also available if we need to go that path.
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Then in your `activity`, you can call URL something like this.

```
    val job = Job()
    val ioScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       ioScope.launch {
            val url ='http://github.com/commits/blah'
            val commitsList = ApiService().getAsyncWay(url)
            println("commitsList list in the coroutine   $commitsList")
            textView.setText(commitsList);
        }
       }
```